# What is the most elegant way to reference a named proposition using cross-references with cleveref and amsthm?

Tags: cross-referencing, best-practices, cleveref, amsthm, thmtools

I have a document in which I have a named proposition, which I wish to reference by its acronym. Since it is named, it ought not be numbered. Still, I'd like to reference it using a cross-reference, rather than hard-coding the acronym, in case I change it (so it gets updated everywhere) or remove it (so I get a warning).

The best I've been able to come up with uses a combination of `thmtools`, `cleveref` and manual definitions of the `cleveref` reference format and of the representation of the relevant LaTeX counter.

All of this seems rather circuitous and - at least in the case of the counter, which I don't even need - unnecessary. However, no simpler approach seems to work.

Dropping the following are NOT really viable options for me at this point as lots now depends on them: `mathtools`, `amsthm` and `cleveref`.

However, `thmtools` can be dropped if, for some reason, a nicer solution is possible without it. (I only started using it to try to deal with this case - I can easily revert to plain `amsthm`.)

Loading `hyperref` is NOT an option, as I can't submit a paper to a journal if it's got hyperlinks. So, even if this would help, I can't use such an approach.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,thmtools,cleveref}
\declaretheorem[numbered=yes, name=Big Friendly Giant, refname={BFG,BFG}]{bfg}
\crefformat{bfg}{#2BFG#3}
\let\thebfg\unskip

\begin{document}
\begin{bfg} Big Friendly Giant theorem \label{thm:bfg}
\end{bfg}

Here's a reference: \cref{thm:bfg}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output (target and desired)]

Note that this output is both what I get and what I want. What is the most elegant way to get it?

If I use `numbered=no` or `numbered=unless unique`, I get an unnumbered proposition (good), but no cross-reference (bad). If I don't redefined `\thebfg`, I get a cross-reference (good), but a numbered proposition (bad). If I set `\thebfg` to `\relax`, I get an unwanted space, which `\unskip` gets rid of. And so on. That is, hackish though this code is, it is the most elegant - or the least inelegant - I've been able to come up with.

Comment: You approach will produce any reference to a `bfg` theorem/proposition as `BFG` then; I do not think that this is what you have in mind? As another solution I suggest to use a normal environment that only 'fakes' the look of a theorem.

Comment: I mean 'your approach' of course... sorry about that typo

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, that really is what I have in mind. That is, the code I posted does what I want. It just seems a very circuitous way of doing it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That is, it might be more convenient to have a more generic environment, of course, such that the tag was specified on each use. My approach requires a distinct theorem type for each named result. However, since I only have one such result in my actual document, this aspect isn't really a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure that I did understand the question. But I would probably do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,thmtools}
\makeatletter
\declaretheorem[numbered=no,name=Big Friendly Giant, postheadhook=\def\@currentlabel{BFG}]{bfg}

\begin{document}
\begin{bfg}[label=thm:bfg] Big Friendly Giant theorem 
\end{bfg}

Here's a reference: \ref{thm:bfg}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So use `\ref` rather than `\cref`? I guess I could do that, provided this still works with `cleveref` loaded. It isn't quite as seamless as using `\cref`, but certainly doable.

Comment: No, \ref is not the main point. The main point is to define \@currentlabel. I only removed the \cref definitions as I didn't really understand their purpose.